# Are $\phi$-contractions weak contraction?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $f:X\longrightarrow X$. We recall:

(*) $f$ is said to be a weak contraction if $d(f(x),f(y))<d(x,y)$ for every $x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$.

(**) $f$ is said to be a $\phi$-contraction if $d(f(x),f(y))\leq \phi(d(x,y))$ for certain  nondecreasing, upper semicontinuous function $\phi:[0,\infty)\longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ with $\phi(t)<t$ for every $t>0$.

On the other hand, [in this paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/97F68AE5CF1E94A2C8FDD5D184EBF6C5/S0004972712000500a.pdf/on_a_certain_generalisation_of_the_iterated_function_system.pdf) (see Remark 2.3) is stated (without proof) that if $X$ is compact, then a weak contraction is a $\phi$-contraction. Do you think that is true of this statement?

Many thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: From your own set of assumptions, $\phi(d(x,y))<d(x,y)$ whether or not $X$ is compact, so it looks like being a $\phi$ contraction is a stronger statement regardless?

Comment: Sorry, the statement was not correct at all: the question is, under the assumption of $X$ be compact, if a weak contraction is a $\phi$-contraction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\phi(t)=\sup \{d(f(x),f(y))|d(x,y)\le t\}$. Then, $\phi$ is obviously non-decreasing and $d(f(x),f(y))\leq \phi(d(x,y))$. Let's argue that $\phi$ is upper semi-continuous.

Let $t\in [0,\infty)$ and $t_n\to t$ from above (which is the only case to check, since $\phi$ is non-decreasing). If $\limsup_{n\to\infty}\phi(t_n)>\phi(t),$ then there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ and sequences $x_n,y_n$ with $t<d(x_n,y_n)\leq t_n$ such that $d(f(x_n),f(y_n))\geq \phi(t)+\varepsilon$. Applying compactness, we can assume that $x_n$ and $y_n$ converge to $x$ and $y$ respectively. By continuity of $d$, $d(x,y)= t$. However, $d(f(x_n),f(y_n))\geq \phi(t)+\varepsilon\geq d(f(x),f(y))+\varepsilon$ which contradicts continuity of $f$. We conclude that $\phi$ is upper semi-continuous.

Now, clearly, $\phi(t)\le t$ since $f$ is a weak contraction. If $\phi(t)=t$ for any $t$, then there exists sequences $x_n,y_n$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)\le t$ and $d(f(x_n),f(y_n))\geq t-\frac{1}{n}$. Applying compactness again, we can assume that $x_n$ and $y_n$ are convergent with limits $x$ and $y$ respectively. However, by continuity, we get that $d(x,y)\le t$ and $d(f(x),f(y))=t$, which contradicts $f$ being a weak contraction. We conclude that $\phi(t)<t$ for every $t$ and you get the desired.

Comment: Thanks very much!